# Wordpress link to Bootstrap Tab

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to be able to link to a tab from another page using the domain.com/about/#History

But it always just loads the base page with the first tab active.

This is my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#About" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#History" data-toggle="tab">Our History</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#Board" data-toggle="tab">Board</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="About" class="tab-pane active">...</div>
<div id="History" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="Board" class="tab-pane">...</div>
<div id="Contact" class="tab-pane">...</div>
</div>
```

I have added the js in the footer but still not working..

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if (location.hash) {
         $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
     }
 });
</script>
```

and I have tried this bit too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var url = document.location.toString();
 if (url.match('#')) {
     $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
 } 
 $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.refresh.hash = e.target.hash;
 })
</script>
```

Any idea of what I am missing, or anything I need to add to Wordpress? Every aspect of Bootstrap is working, I am just having trouble with this.. Thanks for any and all help!

~James

Comment: I think you should use `domain.com/about#History` (without `/`)

Comment: That makes no difference here. The page autosets it to that when loading. Plus on other sites it does that too. I think this might be something with Wordpress.. but obv I am not sure